# Intermittent "Stack Overflow is down for maintenance" errors

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, maintenance

I've been getting these for [at least the past week](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/154002).  Sometimes it will only happen once per day, sometimes a 4 or 5 times per day.  It seems fairly random, mostly happening when I click a link to a question.  It goes away after a refresh or two, but it can be quite annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are active during deployments. I've deployed about five times in the last hour.

Get a new time zone :)

Comment: ...if only I could!

Comment: Well, that's what I tried. If you think changing the DST rules in Oz was hard, try getting a new TZ. I think I may have started a civil war or three as a side effect of trying to push the change through; no luck with the new TZ, so far. They say "who needs a timezone of GMT-2pi?" But one day, I'll show them. I'll show them all! Mwahahaha!!!

Comment: @Andy Not as hard as "get a new name"!

Comment: @Piskvor reminds me of when I got myself my [own currency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro) a few years back. The people I had to have killed... The media I had to buy... Unreliable contractors everywhere. More work than building a house. Never again!